# Why my form doesn't work when it's inside of ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, forms

I'm learning AngularJS and I making simple task management application.
Application is connecting to external rest service. I try to render all my tasks in activities (task's container) with add task button but when form is in loop then it's not sending anything.

Here's my html code:

```
<div id="task-group" ng-repeat="activity in activities | filter:query">
        <p>
        <h2>{{activity.activityName}}</h2></p>
        {{activity.activityId}}
        <form name="form" ng-submit="addTask()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="sendTaskName">
        <input type="hidden" name="{{activity.activityId}}" >
            <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Add task">
        </form>
        <ul class="task-list">
            <li ng-repeat="task in activity.tasks">
                <p>{{task.taskName}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Add task function in my controller:

```
$scope.addTask = function(){
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/add-task',
          data: {taskName: $scope.sendTaskName, activityId: $scope.sendActivityId}
      }).success(function(){
          getActivities()
          $scope.sendTaskName = ''
      })
  }
```

EDIT: @Mickael helps me to solve my problem. The solution is in his answer. Thank you very much once again ! ;)

Comment: you should create a plunkr reproducing your problem and post it here

Comment: Are you sure nothing is sent? Use browser dev tools network to inspect actual requests. Is page on exact same port as the API is on .. 8080? Also should add an error handler

Comment: @charlietfi I used browser tools and parameters are empty. The page is on other ports than api (API: 8080, Page: 6666)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ng-repeat` and inside each iteration, you bind your inputs with the `ng-model` directive.

What happens here is that on each iteration, a new scope is created. When you start typing inside your input, the `sendTaskName` variable is created **inside the scope of the iteration, not the scope of your controller**.

When your form is submitted, you submit the variable of the scope of your controller, that's why you do not send anything.

To solve your problem, I suggest that you give parameters to your `addTask` method:

```
 <div id="task-group" ng-repeat="activity in activities | filter:query">
    <p>
    <h2>{{activity.activityName}}</h2></p>
    {{activity.activityId}}
    <form name="form" ng-submit="addTask(activity.activityId, sendTaskName); sendTaskName = '';">
        <input type="text" ng-model="sendTaskName">
        <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Add task">
    </form>
    <ul class="task-list">
        <li ng-repeat="task in activity.tasks">
            <p>{{task.taskName}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And use these parameters in your controller:

```
$scope.addTask = function(activityId, taskName) {
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/add-task',
      data: {taskName: taskName, activityId: activityId}
  }).success(function(){
      getActivities();
  })
}
```

Next time, with a plunkr, I will be able to fix your code ;)